# Weird behavior with Maps(A nullable expression can't be used as a condition)

Tags: dictionary, dart, null

```
Map<String,bool> map= { "key1":true, "key2":false };

  
  /*
   * Flags following compilation error:
   * A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.
   * Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition.
   */
  if(map["key1"]) {
    //do sth
  }
```

---

```
  /*So I try checking value isn't null as specified in error
   *Still flags same compilation error
   */
   
   if(map!=null && map["key1"]) {
    //do sth
   }
```

---

```
  //This works
  if(map["key1"] == true) {
    //do sth
  }
}
```

Based on the following snippet, may I know why both the 1st and 2nd `if` blocks fail but not the 3rd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the error message.

> A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.

means that you can't do:

```dart
bool? condition;
if (condition) {
  ...
}
```

`Map<K, V>`'s `operator[]` returns a `V?`.  It returns a nullable type as a way of indicating failure when the key isn't found, and you need to check that the returned value isn't `null`, not that `map` itself is not `null`.  For example:

```dart
if (map["key"] ?? false) {
  ...
}
```

Your third approach (which checks `== true`) works because it will perform a `null == true` equality check if the lookup returns `null`.  However, you should prefer using `?? false` since it conveys the intent better, and equality checks against `true` or `false` are usually a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` operator on `Map` can return `null` which makes it nullable which is explained in details here: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#the-map-index-operator-is-nullable

So your first example is invalid since `null` is not a `bool`. So you cannot directly use the value from the `[]` operator for a `Map`.

Your second example is invalid for the same reason since `map["key1"]` is `bool?`.

Third example works since `null == true` is always `false`. So it is fully valid to make a comparison which involves something which can be `null`.